# How do I get a multilevel x axis labelled plot in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, axis, multi-index

I Have a multi-indexed pandas data frame, I can produce the correctly shaped plot for what I require however the x axis is displayed only as the column headers of my multi index. I am after a way of getting a set of layered labels.

What I currently have:

[Current Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnEyA.png)

[The plot using : df.plot(x=None, y=['Published NIV','Future NIV'], kind='line')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oz7tZ.png)

[Circled in blue is how I want the axis to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDIR9.png)

Comment: You want something like this in Python: https://community.qlik.com/legacyfs/online/179822_2017-10-16%2011_08_33-Service%20Complaint%20Report%20-%20Dashboard%20_%20Sheets%20-%20Qlik%20Sense.png

Right?

Comment: Yes please something exactly like that!

Comment: Matplotlib provides major and minor tick levels. They could in principle be used for the two levels of index you have. I can't show you a code here because there is no code/data available in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the question I've worked most on Stackoverflow. I hope this fits your problem perfectly.

So, your period values are from 1 to 48, assuming and that was the only way I could get this, that this is half hourly data, what I did was that I changed these values in half hours of the date provided and then using formatting I changed it to datetimeindex and then created the plot.

So here's the code and final output:

```
m=pd.read_csv("Data3.csv")
final=m[['Published NIV','Future NIV']]

new2=['0:00:00' if a==1 else str(a//2-1)+':30:00' if a%2==0 else str(a//2)+':00:00' for a in m['Settlement Period']]

alpha=m['Settlement Date']+'-'+new2

final.index=pd.to_datetime(alpha,format='%Y-%m-%d-%X')
final.plot(figsize=(15,9))
```

And the output is:
[image]

The only downside I see of this code is that you won't get those period numbers 1 to 48, which with some workaround I can try to bring back, but tell me if this suits your case.

Comment: Firstly thank you for your answer, trouble is for me is that my multi index contains a date and a number spanning from 1 to 48. So unfortunately I don't think it'll quite do the trick. Its certainly barking up the right tree though. If you look at one of the screen grabs in the question you'll see what I'm driving at.

Comment: Well I was assuming that the date was year wise and the numbers were week, so by using datetimeindex it could on it's own create the graph that way. I can give it a try if you send me a toydata via Google Drive or something.

Comment: Ah I see I'm a bit new to all this but I could send you a csv with my data frame? And to get were I am it would only require set index of the settlement date and settlement period?

Comment: Share the link of the csv and I'll see if I am able to get the desired output.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h8dCQC-CWZ12P-EysmQHz3uR6xAh-I50/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: I finally got something, seriously complicated though, but I hope you are going to love it.

Editing in the answer

Comment: Yeah that works for me, in a perfect world  the numbers would be great but I fear it may be too complex to warrant the level of effort. Thank you for your help again. Br Paul

Comment: In that case, I'll really appreciate if you could accept this as the answer to your question. That would help me a lot, Paul.